# webpack entry and output path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a file directory like this

[image]

and my webpack.config.js look like

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './resources/assets/bundle/entries/feed.js'],
  output: {
    path     : path.join(__dirname, 'public/bundle'),
    publicPath : '/',
    filename : 'bundle.js'
  }
}
```

what is wrong? why I did not find the bundle.js in my public/bundle/bundle.js? I run http://localhost:3000/bundle/bundle.js I got 404 error hmm..

Comment: Does localhost:3000/bundle.js return the bundle? You set publicPath equal to '/'

Comment: @kjonsson 404 error

Comment: Where in your file structure is your webpack.config? ^^

Comment: @thesublimeobject root

Comment: @Mellisa Open up devtools and go to sources and see if bundle.js is under localhost:3000. Since your public path is just '/' it should be there under no folder.

Answer (score 0):

In developer mode webpack is not generating the file in the hard-drive.
If you run webpack in production mode you will see the generated file.

Comment: @Mellisa webpack create a "virtual" bundle, so you dont have "source not found" network errors.

Comment: I have a error of 404, my path is correct? I had 2 project, this project I can't get it working, so I guess there's problem with my path above.

Comment: @Mellisa how is your `index.html`

Comment: @Mellisa you shouldnt have localhost there, `<script src="./public/bundle/bundle.js"></script>` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

When you use hot reload or different watcher, webpack generate virtual bundle. If you try to run global command 'webpack' or build project, you can get bundle.js

Comment: ok I assume the file is there but I can't see it, but when I try to access http://localhost:3000/bundle/bundle.js I got 404 error, why?

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.html` we do not mention the path of a file with `localhost` rather relative to the current file. So if `index.html` is in root you will mention the script src as below

```
<script src="./public/bundle/bundle.js"></script>
```